# Make part of a shape/text with no fill

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working on a countdown timer in VBA Powerpoint which takes the input of hour, minutes and seconds and calculate the remaining time which simply counts down to 0

The Working Code:

```
Sub countdown()

Dim time As Date

hours = InputBox("Hour")
minutes = InputBox("Minutes")
seconds = InputBox("Seconds")
time = Date + TimeSerial(hours, minutes, seconds)

Do Until time < Now()

DoEvents
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("startIn").TextFrame.TextRange = "Începem în:"
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("countdown").TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "hh:mm:ss")

Loop

End Sub
```

Now I am trying to hide the hours in my PowerPoint presentation and I tried to make the text fill of just hours with no fill and didn't succeded.. what should I do? I tried this:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("countdown").TextFrame.TextRange.Find("hh:").
```

But from here I was stuck...
I tried to find just the hours part of text in the countdown shape and to make text with no fill.

I am a begginer in VBA.

This is the timer I created in PowerPoint:
[image: This is the timer I created]

Comment: why don't you just change  Format((time - Now()), "hh:mm:ss") to  Format((time - Now()), "mm:ss")

Comment: @userMT , thank you for your suggestion. I tried that and if I put the hour, minutes and seconds after it recalculates it will do this... I will take an example:

If I put: hour = 0, minutes = 1, and seconds = 0. It will replace my timer with: 12:01, where that 12 is from... I don't really know, I can put whatever hour and that 12 will be there instead of 00, and seconds just pass...

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I solved it: I had to format it to "nn:ss"

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer to your own question, it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

For minutes in VBA is better to use nn instead of mm, mm is for months, and nn is for minutes. So that's why I used `Format((time - Now()), "mm:ss")` and I got a 12 instead of minutes, because that was the month. When I put this code `Format((time - Now()), "nn:ss")` I got the minutes and the macro worked well.